# BBpress like/reply notification

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, bbpress

I am struggling to implement a plugin / functionality to catch the likes and replies from a source user (giving the like/reply) and notify the destination user (the author of the post) in bbpress, the forum plugin from wordpress.

Are you aware of existing projects implementing this functionality in bbpress (even partially) ?

Which mechanisms / plugins are better to use to trigger actions in the frontend in this case? On the other hand, is it a better approach to put triggers on the database column?

Thank you for your suggestions !

Comment: Questions like this can always be improved by posting the code you have attempted to write so far, and getting feedback.

Comment: I am more analyzing the database...it has good information, such as user id of the source user, post id. I am talking about the wp_posts table. However, the parent_post is the first post of the topic, so it is not the ierarhical parent post.

I need somehow to identify the nested replies from the database, but I dont find the needed information there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the other hand, there is a second option, maybe more optimized: from phpmyadmin, I created a trigger to populate my table when the information I am interested comes in.

As a conclusion, I couldnt find any free plugin for reply / likes notifications to the user. I had to create one.